# java working with variable declaration and initialization in static methods and main method

Tags: java, variables, initialization, declaration, static-methods

When I run my program I get this:

```
run:
Planetary DataPlanet   Diameter(km)   Mass(kg)   g(m/s^2)
_________________________________________________
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 1
Mercury at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Formatter.java:2936)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2684)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2528)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
at GravityV1.diameterr(GravityV1.java:45)
at GravityV1.main(GravityV1.java:73)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

I am trying to display information made from static methods in the main method. Somehow, it is not displaying it when I call it in the main method, I am also trying to calculate the gravity and it isn't recognizing some of my variables like the universal constant for gravity, I made the gravity static method above the main method and declared and initialized the universal gravity constant in the main method for calculation. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
public class GravityV1 {

// title static method
public static void title(){

    // title
    System.out.printf("%10s", "Planetary Data");

    // heading
    System.out.println("Planet   Diameter(km)   Mass(kg)   g(m/s^2)");

    // create line
    System.out.println("_________________________________________________");
}

// months static method
public static void planetss(){

    // create months array
    String[] planets = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", 
        "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};

    // display planets
    System.out.printf("%5s", (Object[]) planets);
}

// diameter static method
public static void diameterr(){

    // create array of diameter
    double[] diameter = {4880, 12103.6, 12756, 6794, 142984, 120536, 51118, 
        49532};

    // display diameter
    System.out.printf("%4.1d", diameter);
}

// mass static method
public static void masss(){

    // create array of mass
    double[] mass = {3.30E23, 4.869E24, 5.97E24, 6.4219E23, 1.900E27, 
        5.68E26, 8.683E25, 1.0247E26};

    // display mass
    System.out.printf("%4.1d", mass);
}

// gravity calculation static method
public static double gravity(double g){

    // calculate gravity
    g = (G * mass) / Math.pow(diameter / 2, 2);

    return g;
}

// main method
public static void main(String args[]){

    title();
    planetss();
    diameterr();
    masss();

    double G = 6.67384 * Math.pow(10, -11);
}
}
```

Comment: Go read up about variable scope.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - as log as `gravity` is not used (i don't see it called) it doesn't really matter that it return 0 for any g you pass to it :)

Comment: @oerkelens This code won't compile. `G` is declared in a different method than the one it is used in.

Comment: so are mass and diameter, my comment was meant a little bit sarcastic. That method is broken in so many ways, we shouldn't try to sum them up, just hope it doesn;t get called. But you are right, the code shouldn't even compile with this method in it.

Answer (score 2):

[Format specifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for `double` type is not `d` but `f`. You should replace the `printf` statement in `diameterr` method to:

```
System.out.printf("%4.1f", diameter);
```